# Adding new Interface & Replacing Method with Interface Type

Tags: object-oriented, interfaces

Let's say that I have 2 classes: `Foo` and `Bar`.

```
`Foo` {
  List<Bar> bars
  String bippy()
  int boop()
}

`Bar` {
 int biz()
 String baz()
}
```

Observe that `Foo`'s fields include a `List<Bar>`. Note that `Foo` has separate fields from `Bar`, but they share some fields.

Let's say that I have a method, `f`.

```
def f(Foo foo) {
 ...
}
```

This method, `f`, currently accepts only a `Foo` type. However, this method also needs access to a `Bar`.

When I need to pass in a `Bar`, I could simply create a new `Foo` with a single `Bar` in `List<Bar>` - but I don't like this assumption. Placing this assumption in the code won't (and should not be) easily understood by the user of it.

So, I decided to create an interface, `Something`, that both classes implement:

```
interface Something {
 Optional<String> getBippy()
 Optional<int> getBoop()
 Optional<int> getBiz()
 Optional<String> getBaz()
}
```

With this interface, I can now update `f`'s argument to be of type `Something`.

As a result of this new interface, `Foo`'s and `Bar`'s implementations will return "missing" values if the implementing class fails to have the field expected in the interface.

Example:

```
Foo implements Something {
 List<Bar> bars
 getBippy() { return bippy }
 getBaz()   { return None }
 ... // remaining implementations
}
```

This approach will work, I believe, provided that the developer who consumes the `f` method passes in the right type.

How's my approach? In particular, I'm curious if there's a more type/statically safe approach.

Comment: It looks fishy that one method should be able to work with two such completely different classes. Are you sure that it isn't better to split `f`  in two functions (one that works on a `Foo`  and one that works on a `Bar`)?

Comment: That's a very good point. I was leaning towards code re-use (so that I wouldn't need to write two `f` methods: `fFoo` and `fBar`. In addition, I would need to write more `helper` functions if I'm going to support these two functions. But, no doubt, it would be type-safe.

Comment: That interface doesn't guarantee the argument has a Baz (or any other field), and having to modify existing types isn't exactly good code reuse. (Ideally, if I give you some type, you shouldn't have to modify it at all regardless of the context you want to use it in.) I would just write a second function that has a Foo and Bar argument and make it the caller's problem to figure out where to get the Bar.